# Consumo de memória (elemento HTML x objetos jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, memória

Estou criando um sistema onde preciso gravar muitos elementos do DOM em variáveis.

Existe alguma diferença de consumo de memória em gravar os elementos HTML x objetos jQuery?

Elementos HTML:

`var elemento = jQuery('#elemento')[0]; //mesmo que document.getElementById('elemento')`

Objeto jQuery:

`var elemento = jQuery('#elemento');`

Na minha leiga visão, acho que a primeira opção consumiria menos memória por apenas gravar o elemento do DOM, e na segunda é gerado um novo objeto jQuery que carrega dentro dela o tal elemento.

Procede?

Comment: utilizar funções nativas sempre é mais "leve", mas memória só deve ser um problema se o sistema for voltado para celulares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De uma maneira geral isto está correto. O primeiro só grava uma elemento e o segundo todos os elementos. Mas esta diferença pode não ser tão grande assim.

E isto pode ficar armazenado por pouco tempo e logo ser coletado, então faz pouca diferença se está ocupando "muita" memória.

Dependendo do caso pode economizar memória e gastar processamento para ficar pegando coisas que já poderiam estar disponíveis.

Só um teste com a situação real pode indicar qual é o melhor uso. E só deve se preocupar com isto se perceber que está havendo problemas em situações reais.

Comment: Bem observado! No primeiro item eu guardaria apenas o elemento, porém, sempre que eu precisar utiliza-lo eu usaria `$( elemento )`, onde "elemento" é a variável. Então seria mais viável já deixar o objeto jQuery na variável do que ficar criando um novo objeto jQuery sempre que for usar um elemento HTML puro?

Comment: Não sei seu caso real, mas se vai ficar utilizando vários elementos do objeto, então é melhor ficar com o objeto do que ficar pegando os elementos individualmente.